# How to convert a column from Dataframe to Nx1 array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert a column from a dataframe in Python to an array Nx1. What I am trying right now is X = df[['NameOfColumn']].to_numpy(). But this results in (N,) size array instead of (N, 1) I need.
Any suggestion much appreciated.
Thnx.

Comment: Once you learn a bit of basic `numpy` it should be obvious that you can either `reshape` the resulting array, from (N,) to (N,1), or add the dimension with the `[:,None]` syntax.

Comment: It worked. Thnx mate!

Comment: @hpaulj, the [:,None] was just what I needed!